# How do I make a form transparent while keeping the controls fully visible?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, transparency

I would like to have a form in which the controls on the form are fully visible but the form itself is invisible.  If I change the form's `Opacity`, this makes both the form and the controls on it semi-transparent, so this doesn't work.

I can't do this by setting the form's `TransparencyKey`, since I have a `PictureBox` on the form.  If the image in the PictureBox happens to contain pixels that match the `TransparencyKey`, they appear as openings in the form, which I don't want.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking?

Comment: C# doesn't do UI, the framework does UI.  Which framework are you using (WinForm, WPF, Win32?)

Comment: Edited for clarity - feel free to roll back my changes if this isn't what you're asking, but I'm pretty sure it is. I've actually encountered the exact same problem and I'm wondering how to do this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TransparencyKey is the only way to get this.  Pick the right color.  Color.Fuchsia has a long tradition of being the color of choice, going back to the early days of Win32 development.  Assault your eye with it to see its merits.

Answer (score 2):

With the caveat that I've never used it, just ran across it once, thought "neat!" and moved on...

Look into [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbkz3sfb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and setting the form's `Region` property.  I added two buttons to the basic Windows forms application:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(button1.Location, button1.Size);
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(button2.Location, button2.Size);

    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
    gp.AddRectangle(r1);
    gp.AddRectangle(r2);

    this.Region = new Region(gp);
}
```

I've approximated the shape of the button with a rectangle; with this code, you can see the form background color at the buttons' corners.  You'll need to work out the enclosing path for each of your controls and add them to the path individually.  You'll need to take into account any offset introduced by the form title bar or border style.

Update: I did some investigation and have a couple of possible approaches for the problem:

- Using the `GraphicsPath` method, set `pictureBox.Visible` to `False` if there is no image loaded.
- When you load an image into the picture box, analyze the image to get a list of all the colors in it, then randomly generate one that isn't.  Set the form's `BackColor` and `TransparencyKey` properties to match this new color, [Hans Passant's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792321/how-do-i-make-a-form-transparent-while-keeping-the-controls-fully-visible/2795062#2795062) answer.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't do what I want. User control background well still have the form back color. for example if I use a picturebox with .png format image I can still see the form back color.